# Question about my design for my C++ homework

Tags: c++

First, this is for my CS296 class, so everything has to be in the main() function and I can't use anything but loops, switch, and if statements.

Anyway, the program ask the user to enter the number of students in a class, followed by their names. It then displays which student should be at the front of the line and which student should be at the back of the line based on the students being lined up alphabetically from A-Z.

The program runs, but I feel like the design is poor. Specifically with how I'm using the count variable. I was hoping maybe to get some feedback regarding that. Thanks!

```
int main(void)
{
    string front, back, student;
    unsigned short count = 1, students;

    cout << "Enter the number of students in the class. Valid range is 1 - 25." << endl
         << endl
         << "Students: ";
    cin  >> students;

    while (students < 1 || students > 25)
    {
        cout << endl
             << "ERROR: Valid range is 1 - 25" << endl
             << endl
             << "Students: ";
        cin  >> students;
    }

    cout << endl
         << "Enter the name of student " << count << ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, student);

    front = back = student;

    for (count = 2; count <= students; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of student " << count << ": ";
        getline(cin, student);

        if (student < front)
            front = student;
        else if (student > back)
            back = student;
    }

    cout << endl
         << front << " should be at the head of the line." << endl
         << back  << " should be at the end of the line."  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good job on clearly identifying it as homework.

Comment: I don't think it's altogether bad. I'd probably put all the stream extractions and getlines into an `if(...)` check to see if the operation succeeded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that seems fine. Specs called for entering a count and then entering that many students which is exactly what you've done.

Don't get me wrong, the *program* is bad but that's because of ridiculous specs like "everything has to be in the main() function", not anything to do with your implementation.

For this level of homework, I'd be happy getting something like that from my students. It would make a nice change from code that doesn't even compile, single-character variable names everywhere, or an unformatted morass of incorrect indentation and mixed tabs/spaces :-)

Comment: Thanks! (= I really enjoy programming and I try to find the cleanest most efficient way I can to solve a homework problem while staying within the limits of the c++ features I'm allowed to use. It's kind of frustrating that we can't use features that haven't been covered yet, but I'm sure there is a reason for it.

Comment: I find teachers that actively discourage learning by oneself very ... discouraging. They either assume you're so dumb you'll learn everything wrong or that you'll cheat, and never that you might actually be interested in programming. I'm on the first year of my CS major, and the fact that so far, in both Java and C, I could use most of the std. lib. (excepting e.g. qsort() on a quicksort exercise) made my assignments quite less painful since I already had some prior programming experience.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfectly reasonable design to me from an algorithmic perspective. You are just finding the min and max of a list as you are reading the list, and got the hard part right (initializing first and last to the first element). You could use a do-while to make it a bit nice like so:

do{
    //read in, compare to max, min
  }
  while (count < 25)

Comment: The primary difficulty with the `do { ... } while ();` loop is initializing the `front` string so that all values entered compare lower than it on the first cycle.  You then have to compare the entered value to both the `front` and the `back` each time so that both are set on the first cycle (by losing the `else` of the `else if`).

Comment: Yeah, that was why it seemed the first name had to be entered outside the loop. I guess I could have put an if condition in the loop for the first iteration, but I think that would be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only store two students, there's no particular need to limit the number of entries to just 25.  If the user (you) want to add more than 25 names, there's no change needed except in the validation of the number.  Indeed, there is no obvious reason to make the user count the number of students; the code could keep reading students until reaching EOF on `cin`.  However, if the specification says "thou shalt enter the number of names", then your code has to do that, however silly.  But you should allow for early EOF and terminate the loop gracefully if the user only enters 3 names instead of the 20 promised.

It is unfortunate that you cannot use functions of your own; you could use one to prompt for and read the next name, reducing the repetition in your code.

Given those constraints, your code is reasonable.  You could avoid the 'read first name outside of loop' at the cost of more complex checks inside the loop.  The trade-off is probably in favour of what you've written.

Comment: The only reason for the limit of 1-25 was because the assignment called for that, otherwise, I agree. (=